# Account / Accounts / Accounting Department?

Tags: phrase-choice

[Name of Department]

I used to say "Account Department", however I just found that the department in my company is called "Accounts Department".

And when I search Google, most of them are using "Accounting Department".

Just wondered which is/are correct or appropriate? Is there any difference in among different regions? (from Malaysia)

Comment: Both are correct and can be used. [Accounts Department](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/accounts-department) and [Accounting Department](http://financial-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/Accounting+Department)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At times, we need to check what's popular and *is accepted widely*. This is a wonderful example. Searching on [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=account%20department%2C%20accounting%20department%2C%20accounts%20department&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caccount%20department%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccounting%20department%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Caccounts%20department%3B%2Cc0) gives you the results that 'Accounting' is very common, 'Accounts' is less, and 'Account' is rare.

COCA shows favorable results to 'Accounting Department' over 'Accounts'. There again, 'Account' is 'nil'.

We decide looking at these results and practice it. Thinking that if naming a department takes '-ing' then why 'Human Resource Department' and **not** 'Human Resourcing', etc. won't work. Here, 'why' may not be answered precisely.

Again, it depends on the company or the local body. However, if you are the *one* who decides this, choose the most common one i.e. Accounting here.

---

I found ['Accounts Department'](http://theaccountsdept.co.uk/) as bookkeeping practice in the UK!

Comment: Every company I've ever worked for called it the "Accounting Department". (I live in the U.S.)

Answer (score 1):

In small companies both "*Accounts Department*" and "*Accounting*" are used here in the US.  The former is often split into "*Accounts Payable*" and "*Accounts Receivable*", which I suppose due to some differences in whom they need to work with, and in what manner.  It's often represented by a single person managing all the work.

It likely differs from company to company, and once established, rarely changes, I would think.

The expression "*Account Department*" is not in use most likely because that subdivision (even if represented by a single employee) handles *multiple* accounts.

Answer (score 1):

I think, even in U.S., the usage varies by regions.  In my region, Virginia, many companies use a term "Accounting" for a department that processes bookkeeping, issues financial statements, tracks departmental/project budgets and expenses.

Here, Accounting Department is a place where recording and reporting are performed.  For smaller companies, accounting department often does not exist and finance department performs all-things-money.

As to Accounts Department, many companies in my region use that term for a department that is transactional such as sales, Accounts Receivable, and procurement, Accounts Payable, although many companies have AR and AP teams as part of accounting department to track and render transactions that sales/procurement departments report. Sales and procurement employees manage customer accounts and vendor accounts so they often have a job title that includes the word "accounts"--e.g. Accounts Manager.

This is not related to your question but Accounts Management is usually separated from Accounting because it is considered dangerous to have a single person/team to have an authority over all of actions, records, and payment processing for sales/procurement because such power allows a person/team to commit fraud by manipulating prices, invoices/receipts, and payment amounts.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to "Accounting Department".
Reasons:
Accounts Department sounds more like a department that deals with accounts.
Accounting Department sounds more like a department that does the accounting procedures.
I never pay too much attention to this until being asked just now by a colleague and checking this page.